# ¿Esta bien como estoy implementando mi función de updateOrCreate?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Disculpen pero he intentado implementarlo a mi proyecto y no se si este bien como lo esté haciendo:

```
Anuncio::updateOrCreate(
        ['id', $request->anuncioId],
        [
            'nombre'           =>$request->nombreAnuncio,
            'imagen_desktop'   =>$request->imagen_desktop,
            'imagen_movil'     =>$request->imagen_movil,
            'url'              =>$request->urlAnuncio,
            'estado'           =>$request->estadoAnuncio,
            'created_at'       =>Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at'       =>Carbon::now()
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que en el primer array es `['id' => $request->anuncioId]` si tu idea es enviar un solo valor, el cual corresponde al id del modelo.

De la forma como lo tienes planteado actualmente estás enviando dos valores distintos en el array, es como si estuvieras haciendo:

```
[ 0 => 'id', 1 => $request->anuncioId]
```

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias!

Comment: Disculpa, pero si tengo en mi funcion tablas relacionadas la sintaxis sería la misma o cambiaría?